# How to replace values which are in single quotes using a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

Hello I have a text file called "sampleText.txt" which includes string line like this,

```
subscribe_key =  'sub-c-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx';
```

What I need is I need to change this subscribe_key value using bash script. So the given below bash script I used bt it did not work. Hope You will help me to let it work, Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i.bak -r '/^subscribe_key/{s/"[^']+'"/"sub-c-123-456-789"/}' sampleText.txt
```

Comment: Your specified pattern in `s` needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -i.bak -r "/^subscribe_key/s/([^']+')([^']+)('.*)/\1sub-c-123-456-789\3/" yourfile
```